# In background queue run multiple api calls without freezing UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, nsmutableurlrequest

NSURL Async Request gets freeze until the previous api call to complete. 
Our project has a requirement to upload a video into the server, we are doing this using GCD.  But, UI should not be freeze until the upload going to complete.  So, there is a possible to call some other apis too.  But, while calling other apis, these new api calls are waiting for the completion of video uploading api call to finish in queue.

Flow of the application is as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

     //api call for video upload is an NSMutableUrlRequest with Asynchronous completion handler.

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         //UI operations

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

             //simple api call for getting minimal data/ validation ---  (Problem - This api is getting freeze until the video upload to complete).

           });

     });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want that innermost dispatch to wait for the completion of the video, move it outside of that dispatch block, e.g.:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

     //api call for video upload is an NSMutableUrlRequest with Asynchronous completion handler.

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         //UI operations

     });

});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //simple api call for getting minimal data/ validation

});
```

I must say, the original construct seems to suggest some implied dependency between the video and that data validation calls, but if not, you can use something like the above. If you need to know when these two separate asynchronous tasks are both done, you could use a dispatch group.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)? It uses NSURLConnection / NSURLSession for making requests and they are all asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but we are at the ending stage of the application, by this stage we can't able to migrate to AFNetworking.